# way to remove "/home" just from my home page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to Codeigniter.
I want my homepage to be set as "example.com" rather as "example.com/home" currently.

My routes.php is like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

Everything is working fine, just need to know if there is a way to remove "`/home`" just from my home page. Everywhere else is fine.

.htaccess

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: what is happen if you show example.com ?

Comment: It redirects to home @jumpei

Comment: The question is somewhat confusing ... You want example.com/ to open Home/index, but example.com/home to be inaccessible?

Comment: I dont want it to be inaccessible just change the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` file use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(home(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

In your case, maybe this could be solution. Try this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(home(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

php_value session.cookie_httponly 1
php_value session.cookie_secure 1
```

Comment: I helped editing your question. Now edited my answer too. Check if it is working for you.

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS @Tpojka

Comment: Made some changes. Try now.

Comment: I have posted a new .htaccess please have a look @Tpojka because it was showing the same error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: You can't have two `.htaccess` files in same directory. Draw structure of where files are.

Comment: Previous .htaccess was inside a folder, this is the one that works and produce this error.

Comment: Sorry, 'that works and produces error'? I am bit confused. Don't write answers in addition to your question. Please, edit question with all relevant code again.

Comment: it means that this one is the correct .htacces file, previous was not. After changing this .htaccess file, it still produces the same error.

Comment: You say now you have state that doesn't work no matter what? Can you reverse your code to starting position?

Comment: htaccess in my question is the original, but if I post your code in there it produces that error.

Comment: I added one more line. Check it.

Comment: Do you use `index.php` in URL?

Comment: It is just example.com/home

Comment: So when you type `example.com` or `example.com/home` you land on same page, but you want redirect `/home` to `/`. Am I guessing right?

Comment: Code I wrote do just that. Try to put just those two lines in your original file (one that is in question, currently), bellow `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: you want me to remove the last line of my htaccess, is it that?

Comment: RewriteRule . /index.php [L]      this line I mean @Tpojka

Comment: No just add two separated lines from my answer to your file between lines `RewriteBase /` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`.

Comment: its same error if I add your two lines between RewriteBase / and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f in original file

Comment: It is really hard when you just jump in the middle of a project, hate it.

Comment: I used example from [here](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/) ([or here](https://github.com/Tpojka/general-ci-htaccess)) and it worked for me every time.

Comment: It didnt work for me. is there any way to remove the controller name in the url, from within the same controller. or maybe hide that segment.

Answer (score 0):

Just write in your .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

in your routes.php

and check

```
$config['base_url']='http://exemple.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

then  example.com will show example.com/home controller but wont display the '/home' uri segment. It works fine for me